# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.metrics' has no attribute 'F1Score'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, metrics

<< I already imported import tensorflow_addons as tfa
when I am running the below code

```
    densenetmodelupdated.compile(loss ='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd_optimizer, metrics= 
      ['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
                        tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),   
                        tf.keras.metrics.AUC(),
                        tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=25, average="macro")])
```

<< it shows error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-5f3ab8b4cc77> in <module>()
     16                         tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
     17                         tf.keras.metrics.AUC(),
---> 18                         tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=25, average="macro")])                        

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.metrics' has no attribute 'F1Score'
```

Comment: Did you install it using `pip install tensorflow-addons`?

Comment: yes sir but still it is giving me this error. i have installed too andalso import tensorflow_addons as tfa

Comment: Can you share standalone code to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tensorflow_addons 0.16.0 with Tensorflow 2.7.0, `tfa.metrics.F1Score` works just fine.

**Working sample code**

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
import numpy as np
metric = tfa.metrics.F1Score(num_classes=3, threshold=0.5)
y_true = np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                   [1, 0, 0],
                   [1, 1, 0]], np.int32)
y_pred = np.array([[0.2, 0.6, 0.7],
                   [0.2, 0.6, 0.6],
                   [0.6, 0.8, 0.0]], np.float32)
metric.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
result = metric.result()
result.numpy()
```

**Output**

```
array([0.5      , 0.8      , 0.6666667], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `v2.13`, `F1Score` was added to `tf.keras.metrics` so normally you no longer need `tensorflow-addons`.

> Added F-Score metrics `tf.keras.metrics.FBetaScore`, `tf.keras.metrics.F1Score`, and `tf.keras.metrics.R2Score`.

Check [v2.13.0 release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.13.0)